# Fatal Error: How to Increase Memory Limit

Tags: php, api, json, khan-academy

I am trying to use the Khan Academy API but I am running into a small problem. I believe the data being returned by the API call is too large for the variable that is holding the data. I did some Googling and came across a method that sets `memory_limit` equal to `-1`. I tried this but it did not seem to work for me. Here is the error I am receiving:

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 125829120 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 86 bytes) on line 20**

Line 20 refers to `$array = json_decode($output, true);`

Here is my full code:

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

$options = array(
       CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topictree",
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

$array = json_decode($output, true); //Saves the returned JSON object as a multi-dimensional array

foreach ($array as $key => $subarray) {

    if ($subarray['readable_id'] == 'financial-crisis-in-thailand-caused-by-speculative-attack') {
        echo $subarray['readable_id'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you self-hosting? A hosting provider might be limiting your memory usage, rendering your memory_limit useless!

Comment: Which PHP version are you on?

Comment: Yep, probably hosting limiting it, but: a `$output=json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/topictree"));var_dump(memory_get_peak_usage(true));` reports only 64,225,280 in use here... Less then half your limit, and no errors. Is this a standalone script or is something running before this?

Comment: This is a stand alone script nothing is running beofre it.

Comment: Are you really looping through that whole tree to find one items (or type of item - I'm not familiar with the API)?  Does the API not give you a better means to query only the data you need directly?

Comment: It does not have a better means unfortunately. You have to query the entire database basically to get one item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

Answer (score 0):

memory_limit = 16M in php.ini.  Some servers like godaddy's are php5.ini.  Whichever one you are using.  Change the value to be as big as you need.

https://drupal.org/node/29268

This link is information for drupal.  But, should work around the board.